# How to set the theme from a database setting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 site, and want to allow the site owner to be able to change the theme (controlled by the appropriate CSS file). I have an admin app that allows them to update the Theme field of the Settings table (which only ever contains one entry).

The admin app uses WCF to communicate with the web site. In order to avoid hitting the database on every single page view, and also to avoid adding code to the _Layout.cshtml file, I added a class as follows...

```
public partial class Setting {
  public static string ThemeName { get; set; }
}
```

When the admin app sends an updated Setting entity to the WCF service, it does the following...

```
Setting.ThemeName = setting.Theme;
```

...which I thought would give the whole site the new value. The _Layout.cshtml file then does this...

```
<link href="/Content/Themes/@Setting.ThemeName/Theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, even when the WCF service call updates Setting.Theme, the  _Layout.cshtml file still gets the old value.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or of a better way to do this? I thought a static property of the Setting class would be available everywhere in the web project, but it seems that when the WCF service call updates it, the _Layout.cshtml doesn't see the change. They are both in the same project by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, due to the complete lack of any suggestions here, I ended up writing the value to a small text file, and reading it in in the _Layout.cshtml file. Not really the way I would have liked to have done it, but it works.